# Add Continue Shopping button in checkout page Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart

Can anyone help me on how to add the "Continue Shopping" button?

[image]
please see attached screenshot.
https://imghostr.com/ySnHx3Cb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your custom theme is extending `luma` theme.

By default in luma theme, `Continue Shopping` and `Clear Shopping Cart` are available but hide using CSS.

You need to inspect in browser search for class `action continue` and remove `display: none;`

[image]

Hope above will help!